# Weird HTML characters - translate using php?

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, domdocument

I am receiving data from a webcrawler using `DOMDocument` and here is an example of something that I need assistance on:

`Around theÂ Webâ€¦`

As you can see, there are many weird characters in that sentence. How do I translate that to a viewable sentence? Is there a `php function`?

Comment: `htmlentities` should do the trick - http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Is the data being read from a URL, or from a local file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the encoding of the characters. When reading the DOM, also retrieve the character encoding and use that to to read the text:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: Ok. How do I read the character encoding? Is this accessible through the `DOMDocument`? And then, what encoding do I translate it to - UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

The problem obviously with encoding

There can be several options:

1. Why do think it has weird symbols? do you see it in ASCII console or in ASCII db? Check place were you store the data and set UTF8 as encoding
2. Check the source - XML file which is taken from crawler should have proper encoding

PS. you will need mb_convert_encoding function in case your input data is not UTF8, but you're storing them as utf8

UPDATE: here is utf8 save php file which works properly:

```
$original_string = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /></head><body><a href="/around-the-web/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Around the&nbsp;Web…">Around the&nbsp;Web…</a></body></html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($original_string);

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo $doc->actualEncoding . '<br>';
echo $doc->xmlEncoding . '<br>';

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: I tried all permutations of `header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo mb_convert_encoding("Around theÂ Webâ€¦",'UTF-8');` and it still returning the sentence using those special characters. The data is coming straight from a web crawler and i'm viewing it on my browser (chrome).

Comment: do not use mb_convert_encoding with copy-pasted wrong string, it will not work, what do you see in chrome? please provide actual source code of xml file

Comment: `<a href="/around-the-web/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Around the&nbsp;Web…">Around the&nbsp;Web…</a>`. Ill check without copy pasting now

Comment: @jkushner check update answer, looks like file from crawler do not set proper encoding in output